# Regex - Buscar cadena SL en distintos formatos

Tags: php, regex, php7, php5, php-5.6

quiero hacer una regex para buscar posibles combinaciones de "SL" , siendo posible estas combinaciones validas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero quiero que este caso no sea válido

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La regex que tengo actualmente construida es esta pero me falla solo para el primer caso, dejo una captura con la regex.

La regex es : \s[s?]?[.][l]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código PHP que uso es este y lo hago sobre php 7.3

```
$re = '/\s[s?]?[\.\][l]/m';
$str = '';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Por favor, agrega el codigo para ver que estas haciendo, y por que pones tantos tags de versiones de php ?? Estás usando 3 versiones de inmediato ??

Comment: Estoy usando php7.3

Answer (score 0):

`\b` coincide en una *posición* entre un caracter alfanumérico y uno que no es alfanumérico. Se usa para coincidir con límites de palabras.

```
/\bS\W*L\b/
```

Además, agregué `\W+` entre medio de las 2 letras, permitiendo cualquier cantidad de caracteres no alfanuméricos.